# cast deconstructed object to a type in one line?

Tags: javascript, typescript

```
const { myMethod } = something[0].play;
```

how can I cast myMethod to string?

this won't work

```
const { myMethod } = something[0].play as string;
```

Comment: `as {myMethod: string}` probably, but what is `something`?  Can you provide a [mre] so we don't have to guess?

Answer (score 0):

If myMethod is assignable to type 'string':

```
const { myMethod }: { myMethod: string } = something[0].play;
```

Otherwise you have to cast it at the cost of not destructuring:

```
const myMethod = something[0].play.myMethod.toString();
// or
const myMethod = String(something[0].play.myMethod);
```